# Can you verify a mock object if you don't have its Moq-wrapper?

Tags: .net, moq

Can anyone explain to me how to verify mocks if you don't have their Moq-wrapper? `MockFactory.Verify()` won't do. I want to be able to verify the mocks explicitly and mocks should be created using mockfactory! Please send in your comments.

Comment: give a small sample of the key steps you want to do. Will they be Strict? What does "wont do" mean? Why is it insufficient? Or will it not work for you? is VerifyAll any more use?

Comment: When implementing mocks using MocksFactory,I had implemented some of them to optionally take Boolean parameters to specify whether to add a verify to the setup of some of the methods, which would cause the verify to occur when calling mockFactory.Verify().But I think, it is more understandable reading the unit test if we use the Verify method directly on the mock object in the unit test rather than using mockFactory. And I want to know how  that can be done?? Any help??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create your mocks using a factory, it doesn't mean you must verify them using it. Sometimes I use factory only to set up `MockBehavior` in one place for all my mocks. But I still verify some of my mocks separately.

```
var factory = new MockFactory(MockBehavior.Strict);
var fooMock = factory.Create<IFoo>();

fooMock.Setup(foo => foo.Bar());

fooMock.Verify(foo => foo.Bar, Times.Once());
```

**Update**
In case if you only have mocked objects in your test method, you can get mock wrappers back like this:

```
IFoo foo = fooMock.Object;

//...

var fooMockAgain = Mock.Get(foo);
```

Comment: Actually I have a class in which functions are written to create required mocks using mockfactory along with the setups. These functions only return the real object i.e. mockedthing.object 
So in the main function i just call these functions to create the dummy objects. So here i seem to be able to  verify only using mockfactory. I want to know if there is any other way.